# Show info when hovering over voronoi polygons (in D3.js)

Tags: d3.js, hover, tooltip, voronoi

I want to show the city name and population related to the voronoi area hovered over. However, with how I made the voronoi areas, I had to either only send coordinate data and have all of the drawings work, or send more data and none of the voronoi areas are drawn (b/c it can't read the non-coordinate data, and I don't know how to specify within an array or object, at least when creating voronois). I can enter static or irrelevant data for the tooltip (as I did below), but not anything from the actual dataset.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
        .clipExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]]);

d3.csv("us-cities1.csv", function(d) {
    return [projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[0], projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[1]];
        }, function(error, rows) {
            vertices = rows;
            drawV(vertices);
            }
        );

function polygon(d) {
        return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
}

function drawV(d) {
    svg.append("g")
       .selectAll("path")
       .data(voronoi(d), polygon)
     .enter().append("path")
       .attr("class", "test")
       .attr("d", polygon)
       .attr("id", function(d, i){return i;})
       .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
       .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px").text((this).id);})
       .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});

    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(d)
     .enter().append("circle")
       .attr("class", "city")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; })
       .attr("r", 2);
        }
```

Comment: You can specify accessor functions for x and y for voronoi (see [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Voronoi-Geom#wiki-x)). This allows you to specify how to extract the coordinates and you can have other data.

Comment: I apparently am not understanding how to use that syntax. Would you be able to provide a quick example? My data has headers "rank", "place", "population", "lat", and "lon". I've tried many variations, but the one I thought made the most sense was:

d3.csv("us-cities1.csv", function(d) {
 svg.append("g")
           .selectAll("path")
           .data(voronoi.x(+d.lon).y(+d.lat), polygon)
....

Comment: That should work, but then in your mouseover function you have to add in the code to access the data (which will automatically be passed as the first parameter of the mouseover function) and set the tooltip text.  Tutorial [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch10.html#_binding_event_listeners) from Scott Murray's *Interactive Data Visualization for the Web*.

Comment: Unfortunately, the syntax that I use doesn't work. It won't even create the voronoi. I get the following error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: It seems that I can't use the voronoi method unless I translate my data into an array of only coordinates. But if that is the case, how do I dynamically access other information that I want to be tied to those coordinates?

Comment: Could you post a working example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together an example using your data to demonstrate what Lars mentions. I created a variable for Voronoi like this:

```
var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .x(function(d) { return (d.coords[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return (d.coords[1]); });
```

which was taken from this [Bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400) by Mike.  This allows you to specify the array of coordinates and still have them connected to the descriptive data you want to display.

I then created the object to store all the data in a format that could be used in the Voronio polygons using:

```
cities.forEach(function (d,i) {
    var element = { 
            coords: projection([+d.lon, +d.lat]),
            place: d.place,
            rank: d.rank,
            population: d.population
        };
    locCities.push(element);
});
```

I could have specified the translation of the coordinates in the voronio variable and then just used the `cities` variable, but I didn't.

The title attribute was used for the tooltips, but this can be replaced with something more appropriate such as what you have in your code.  The relevant code is :

```
.append("title") // using titles instead of tooltips 
    .text(function (d,i) { return d.point.place + " ranked " + d.point.rank; });
```

There were a few issues with the data.  I had to use an older version of d3 (3.1.5) to get the geojson to render correctly.  I know there have been a number of chnanges to the AlberUsa projection so beware there is an issue there.

The location of some of the cities seems wrong to me for instance San Fancisco appears somewhere in Florida (this caused me some confusion). So I checked the original csv file and the coordinates seem to be wrong in there and the data is rendering where it should (just not where I'd expect according to the labels).

Now putting it all together you can find it [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/8363969)

Comment: Thank you! I also found the same [Bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400), which clued me in on the proper place to specify the voronoi .x an .y accessor functions. That alone was huge. Your method of pushing relevant data onto an array stack is neat, and I can imagine using that to elegantly combine information from different data sets.